# When viewing a contribution the Line Items do not display

Tags: contributions, line-items

Whenever a contribution is displayed it is now possible to click on the total amount of the contribution and it should display further details of the line item(s). Where there is a single line item the details are correctly displayed. However where a contribution consists of two or more line items only a single line is displayed with the total amount but under the heading Financial Type there are as many Financial Type descriptions displayed as there are line items. You can see this in the attached screen shot. There are three line items that make up the $550 and there are three Financial Type labels under the heading  Type.

[image]

Comment: did you replicate this on dmaster.demo?

Comment: What are you using for CMS and what version of Civi are you using? Did this work correctly for you in the past?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.53 and CiviCRM 4.7.15. I cannot remember which version of CiviCRM introduced the ability to view line items but I have never been able to view multiple line items.